# Does a WOL to broadcast IP send wake-on-LAN command to all computers on LAN?

Tags: wake-on-lan

I'd like to be able to wake-on-LAN all the computers in my home lab. Can I simply send a WOL packet to 192.168.1.255/24 and wake computers on my LAN? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes and no.

The WoL packets as a whole are usually broadcast, in order to reach NICs which have no IP address. However, the packet data – the "magic packet" itself – needs to contain the machine's individual MAC address. So if you use the wake-on-magic-packet feature it's always directed.

The same applies to most kinds of wake-on-pattern features: while many cards allow programming a set of custom wake patterns (e.g. ARP queries, TCP SYNs), many operating systems have [a hardcoded list](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617165(v=ws.10).aspx) of such patterns and they're *all* specific to the host as well. (Waking up the whole subnet is *rarely* a desired feature.)

With Linux you might be able to program the same generic WoL pattern into all hosts; however it would be much easier to just send a bunch of individual WoL packets with a simple shellscript.

Comment: That makes sense about it sending to a specific MAC address, thanks. I would like to take everything in my ARP cache while all my machines are on, then save the MAC's and send a WOL to all of them, so I'll look into a way to script this with Linux. Sounds like a good learning experience.